# why there is undefined when i run this

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<html>
<head>
<title>js_trial</title>

<script language="javascript">
now = new Date();

document.write("today is: "+now+"<br/>");


function print (number){
if(number >= 4);

return document.write("the number "+number);
}

var num = 4;
var doub = print(num);

document.write(doub);
</script>
</head>
<body>





</html>
```

output:
today is: Wed Feb 15 2012 23:31:19 GMT+0800 (Taipei Standard Time)
the number 4undefined

why there is undefined after 4?

Comment: I'm guessing it's because because `window.print()` returns `void`

Comment: `language="javascript"`? You appear to be using a tutorial that is teaching HTML 3.2. You might want to find [something more up to date](http://www.w3.org/wiki/Web_Standards_Curriculum#JavaScript_core_skills).

Answer (score 2):

The return value of `document.write` is always `undefined`.

You `document.write` the return value of `print` which has `return document.write(...)`.

Answer (score 2):

Your if statement is not working:

```
now = new Date();

document.write("today is: "+now+"<br/>");

function print (number){
    if(number >= 4) {   
        document.write("the number "+number);
    }
}

var num = 4;
print(num);
```

And there is no response from `document.write`. Therefor 'undefined'.

Comment: I'm sure, you know that, but `if(number >= 4) 
        document.write("the number "+number);` without `{}` would work too. The `;` is breaking it though.

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing when you call `document.write(doub);` is essentially `doucment.write(document.write("the number "+number));`.

`undefined` is the return value of the inner `document.write` call, which the outer document.write call is telling you has no value.

Comment: this solution helped me. forced me to double check my syntax. ty

Answer (score 0):

the function document.write always returns undefined!
What you do is: write "the number 4" to you document (`document.write("the number "+number);`) and store the return value of your write function (undefined) to the variable `doub` After that, you then write `doub` to your document as well which results in the appended "undefined".

what you would want to write instead of you code, is:

```
function print (number){
   if(number >= 4){
      return ("the number "+number);
   }
}

var num = 4;
var doub = print(num);
document.write(doub);
```

your function print now returns a string "the number 4" which is stored in `doub` and finally written to the document.

OR

```
function print (number){
   if(number >= 4){
      document.write("the number "+number);
   }
}

var num = 4;
print(num);
```

You call the function print, which writes "the number 4" to the document directly.

EDIT:

`<script language="...">` is outdated, use `<script type="text/javascript">` instead!

Your if condition does not work, use

```
  if (condition) {
     //your code here
  }
```