# Why is there an "undefined" next to a string when using OOP?

Tags: javascript, undefined

I'm currently using OOP to display cooking recipes. Everything is fine, except for when I use the `document.write` method. The text displays as "$2.00undefined" and "$6.00undefined" when displaying the `price`. Here's my code:

```
<html>
    <body>
    <p id = "p"></p>
<script>
function Recipe(name, ingredients, price) {
    this.name = name;
    this.ingredients = ingredients;
    this.price = price;
}

function describe(name, ingredients, price) {
    document.write("<h2> Recipe name: " + name + "</h2> Ingredients: " + ingredients + "<br  />Price: " + price);
}

var instantRamen = new Recipe("Ramen", "Ramen noodles, hot water, salt, (optional) green pepper", "$2.00");
var Bagel = new Recipe("Ham and cheese bagel", "Bagel (preferably an everything bagel), ham, cheese (of any type), pepper (just a little)", "$6.00");

document.write(describe(instantRamen.name, instantRamen.ingredients, instantRamen.price));
document.write(describe(Bagel.name, Bagel.ingredients, Bagel.price));
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

The expected outcome would be something like "Recipe name: Ramen (linebreak)
Ingredients: Ramen noodles, hot water, salt, (optional) green pepper (linebreak)
Price: $2.00", but the Price becomes "$2.00undefined." Everything else works.

I originally thought there was something wrong when creating the `instantRamen` and `Bagel` instances, so I tried changing some syntax with no avail.

Comment: Here's a jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/sirswagger21/yq7crnze/. I tried using the "Run Code Snippet" when editing my question, but then @jonrsharpe changed it back.

Comment: The return value of `describe()` is `undefined` which you also write out `document.write(describe(`. Remove the `document.write(` here or better remove it inside of `describe()` and just `return` the string.

Comment: Seems like similar question: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9296284/why-there-is-undefined-when-i-run-this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9296284/why-there-is-undefined-when-i-run-this)

Comment: So you are basically calling `document.write(document.write(...));` and document.write returns only "undefined"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can `return` your function like this.

Because you are not returning any value. Thatsy `undefined`

```js
function Recipe(name, ingredients, price) {
    this.name = name;
    this.ingredients = ingredients;
    this.price = price;
}

function describe(name, ingredients, price) {
    return "<h2> Recipe name: " + name + "</h2> Ingredients: " + ingredients + "<br  />Price: " + price;
}

var instantRamen = new Recipe("Ramen", "Ramen noodles, hot water, salt, (optional) green pepper", "$2.00");
var Bagel = new Recipe("Ham and cheese bagel", "Bagel (preferably an everything bagel), ham, cheese (of any type), pepper (just a little)", "$6.00");

document.write(describe(instantRamen.name, instantRamen.ingredients, instantRamen.price));
document.write(describe(Bagel.name, Bagel.ingredients, Bagel.price));
```

```html
<html>
    <body>
    <p id = "p"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

I have removed `document.write` and `return` the string.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is you are calling the function `describe` inside the `document.write` function. It writes *undefined* because describe returns nothing.

What is happening is: first, the `describe` function write the html text in the document. Then, you try to write the return of `describe` function in the document.

You do not need to put the `describe` function inside `document.write.` Just call it with the parameters you want.

Comment: This answer is correct. A suggestion, a better code practice is to split the responsibilities and to make the `describe` function return just the string, and then use that result with `document.write`.

Answer (score 1):

Now its working

```html
<html>
    <body>
    <p id = "p"></p>
<script>
function Recipe(name, ingredients, price) {
    this.name = name;
    this.ingredients = ingredients;
    this.price = price;
}

function describe(name, ingredients, price) {
    document.write("<h2> Recipe name: " + name + "</h2> Ingredients: " + ingredients + "<br  />Price: " + price );
}

var instantRamen = new Recipe("Ramen", "Ramen noodles, hot water, salt, (optional) green pepper", "$2.00");
var Bagel = new Recipe("Ham and cheese bagel", "Bagel (preferably an everything bagel), ham, cheese (of any type), pepper (just a little)", "$6.00");

//edited
describe(instantRamen.name, instantRamen.ingredients, instantRamen.price);
describe(Bagel.name, Bagel.ingredients, Bagel.price);
document.getElementById("p").innerHTML = "Your browser version is " + navigator.appVersion;
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue has nothing to do with OOP pattern here, this question is similar to this one "[why there is undefined when i run this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9296284/3048306)"

The issue mainly because you are performing double calls on `document.write(...)`,
as in first you call it to print whichever is returned by the `describe(...)` function, which in this case is always going to be `undefined`, and therefore the original call to `document.write` will print exactly that.

In short, the issue is in your code, and has nothing to do with using OOP here.

Here is your code after removing the double calls for `document.write`:

```html
<html>
    <body>
        <p id="p"></p>
        <script>
            function Recipe(name, ingredients, price) {
                this.name = name;
                this.ingredients = ingredients;
                this.price = price;
            }
            
            function describe(name, ingredients, price) {
                // >>>> Removed the call to `document.write`, and replaced it with
                //      `return `
                return "<h2> Recipe name: " + name + "</h2> Ingredients: " + ingredients + "<br />Price: " + price;
            }
            
            var instantRamen = new Recipe(
                "Ramen", 
                "Ramen noodles, hot water, salt, (optional) green pepper", 
                "$2.00");

            var Bagel = new Recipe(
                "Ham and cheese bagel", 
                "Bagel (preferably an everything bagel), ham, cheese (of any type), pepper (just a little)", 
                "$6.00");
            
            document.write(describe(instantRamen.name, instantRamen.ingredients, instantRamen.price));
            document.write(describe(Bagel.name, Bagel.ingredients, Bagel.price));
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```